# distributional derivation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

i take a course about partial differential equations and we follow the book by Rauch.

In the appendix of the book are some excercises about computing distributional derivation and i´m struggling about to compute

$\frac{\mathrm{d^{k}}}{\mathrm{dx^{k}}} |\sin(x)| $.

My first idea was to start with the formula

$ \langle\frac{\mathrm{d^{k}}}{\mathrm{dx^{k}}} |\sin(x)| , \varphi \rangle  = (-1)^{k} \langle|\sin(x)|,\frac{\mathrm{d^{k}}}{\mathrm{dx^{k}}} \varphi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\sin(x)|\frac{\mathrm{d^{k}}}{\mathrm{dx^{k}}} \varphi \mathrm{dx} $

but then i got no idea how to go on, because i dont how to split the integration interval that i can use partial integration.

I hope someone can help me with this "easy" calculation

Comment: my problem is more like this: Take for example compute:       $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} |x| $ then i would start like$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x| \varphi(x) \mathrm{dx} = - \int_{-\infty}^{0} x \varphi(x) \mathrm{dx} +\int_{0}^{\infty} x \varphi(x) \mathrm{dx} $ . and then use partial integration, but in my question i dont see how to start.